# How to access my runnnig server at aws ec2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, web

I have running Angular project in EC2-instance in AWS. It states that

/*NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

How can i access that running server?

In another system.

Answer (score 2):

1. For your EC2 instance edit the security group to include inbound traffic for port 4200
2. Use the following command to run the dev server `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
3. `http://AWS_Public_IP:4200/`  will open up the page

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify if your EC2 instance is Windows or Linux?

If Linux,

1. Please execute ifconfig command and get the "Private IP" of your EC2 instance
2. Then start ngserve like using the command below:

   **ng serve --port 4200 --host *your_private_ip***

   Eg. if your Private IP is 10.0.0.122, then run ng serve with command 
   "*ng serve --port 4200 --host 10.0.0.122*"
3. Then try to access from other VM within the AWS itself like "http://*your_private_ip*:4200"
4. In case your EC2 is having a elastic IP attached to the instance, you can access it from internet using the URL "http://*your_elastic_ip*:4200"

Note: Enabling the port 4200 in the Security group of your EC2 instance is mandatory to access this. Please let me know if you need help on that as well.

Comment: Please note that binding the ng server to the private ip is mandatory for accessing your application from other servers;  be it from the same VPC or from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you EC2 instance has a public IP or DNS you can use that with 4200  port. If you want a consistent public IP over server restarts use elastic IP instead. Also you need to open the corresponding port in your security group your EC2 instance is part of.

If another system is in same VPC as the EC2 server that you can use the private IP to connect to it. Just make sure port is made accessible through security groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Port is Made accessible,and i tried connecting through "my_elastic_ip:4200",But didn't  load.